TCP Proxy protocol deserialization with Spring Integration
I'm attempting to workout the best way to parse a proxy protocol header over a TCP connection. The data in the proxy header is used to determine if the connection should be accepted or rejected.
The TCP payload is streaming data so there are no definable "messages". We use a custom deserializer that simply reads the InputStream and returns a byte[] containing whatever was in the stream at the time.
protected final byte[] doDeserialize(InputStream inputStream, byte[] buffer) throws IOException
{
    int len = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    if (len < 0)
        throw new IOException("Stream closed");
    return this.copyToSizedArray(buffer, len);
}

This question seems very close to what I need but it was asked 10 years ago and I'm hoping there is some updated capability in the Spring Integration TCP/IP library (How to implement TCP connection handshaking with Spring Integration?).
From what I've researched these are the potential solutions:

Read the proxy header in the deserializer and somehow inform the TCP Server Factory to drop/keep the connection
Read the deserialized byte[]s in a TCP Interceptor but risk complication if the proxy header is split into multiple messages
Create a custom ServerConnectionFactory that somehow performs this logic


I faced similar issue and got resolved
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73253127/why-do-requests-interfere-with-one-another-requests-and-slow-performance-with-sp

The logic in TcpNetConnection is like this:
private boolean receiveAndProcessMessage() {
    Message<?> message = null;
    try {
        message = getMapper().toMessage(this);
        this.lastRead = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        publishConnectionExceptionEvent(e);
        if (handleReadException(e)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

So, if you throw an exception from your Deserializer, a TcpConnectionExceptionEvent  is going to be emitted.
Plus that handleReadException() has the logic like:
    if (checkTimeout(e)) {
        boolean readErrorOnClose = !isNoReadErrorOnClose();
        closeConnection(true);

So, all good to parse that header in your Deserializer and throw some exception to enforce connection to be closed.

Thanks for pointing that out! The validation process involves making an HTTP call, so I was worried about complicating the deserializer, but if that doesn't sound like a problem I will move forward with that approach.

Streaming Protocols:

TCP is a streaming protocol. Serializers and Deserializers demarcate messages within the stream
1

My Use Case:
I was working on a similar project where I need a custom serializers and deserializers for the TCP sockets.
You would need to have a custom deserializer for the TCP message.
In my case, my TCP data looks something like [message1,message2,message3].
So, basically my TCP data ends with the ] character.
And if there is something wrong
Example: [message1],message2,message3..etc]
I would close my socket and create a new TCP socket and do again the handshaking.
In your case, you also need to know what will be demarkation.

It could be either some character like ].
Predefined length.

For my use case, I used to work with the EMV cards, which has maximum value of 300 bytes.
You can take a reference from my custom deserializer:
@Component
class CustomDeserializer extends DefaultDeserializer {
  private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 300;

  @Override
  public Object deserialize(final InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(MAX_LENGTH);
   
    int read = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int loop = 0;
    while(read != ']') {
      read = inputStream.read();
      sb.append((char) read);
      if(loop++ >300) { //I knew my max value could be upto 300 bytes. 
         throw new RuntimeException("Illegal State Exception");
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

